# Am I using the Google Apps Script Lock Service correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have 3 Apps Script functions in a script. The script is deployed as a public access Web App.

Each function reads from a it's own google sheet.  Each function does not write anything to the sheets.

I have applied the Apps Script 'LockService' to each function to prevent multiple users accessing the spreadsheets, via the webapp, at the same time. In effect making each user wait until the previous user's script has finished reading.  They they get to read the 3 sheets.

I've found this can sometimes create a bit of a delay of 4 or 5 seconds for users before the App is updated - which is quite off putting.

My question then is should I -
a) bother with the LockService, as I am just reading the spreadsheet data and perhaps the main purpose of LockService is to prevent conflicts between concurrent read AND writes

Or

b) am I correct to implement it, as reading data concurrently could also cause conflicts is getting things like Range values etc.

thanks

EDIT:  if option 'a' then I wonder what the purpose of LockService is? Is one reason perhaps (as I have elsewhere in other scripts) when you use multiple 'google.script.run.'  One after the other to access the same spreadsheet, via different functions, then -  as these run asynchronously - there could be conflicts created if both requests are trying to Get data.

just musing really....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use the `LockService` if all you're doing is reading data. Therefore, option (a).

There's no need to protect Apps Script or Google Sheets from concurrency, even write operations from the same user. Each parallel access you do from Apps Script runs completely independently from each other, it is a new instance of your app that do not share anything with others, it might even be running on a different server entirely. And Google Sheets handle concurrency just fine, concurrent collaboration is the whole point of the G Suite apps.

So, when do you need `LockService`?

When your app logic requires such. For example, to protect itself from messing up its own data. Let's say you want to count how many clicks you had and save that number on a sheet, e.g. `Sheet1!B2`. So your code would look like:

```
function countClicks() {
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B2');
  var clicks = r.getValue();
  clicks = clicks + 1;
  r.setValue(clicks);
}
```

If this function runs concurrently, you're not going to corrupt your memory or make Google Sheets break, all that's going to happen is that you might overwrite yourself, as if you had multiple users trying to type in the same cell: the last one wins.

But your logic would be broken, that is, multiple concurrent clicks may be counted as a single one. That's when [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) comes in, to protect your logic:

```
function countClicks() {
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B2');
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(10000); //throws exception if fails to acquire lock
  //you could try-catch it, but that's irrelevant in this example
  r.setValue(r.getValue()+1);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //forces the script to actually send the values to Sheets
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Hopefully this clarifies it.

By the way, this is just a very lame example. This is not how you should count clicks because, as you've pointed out, locking adds a significant delay in your system. Therefore you should look for alternatives, maybe splitting your data per user or using atomic operations like [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents).

Comment: Thanks.  One thing to add is the Web App is deployed as 'Me' but accessible by  'Anyone inc anonymous'.  So does this affect my concurrent access concerns and therefore the need for LockService - in that, it is the same user account with many different users.

Comment: massive win with reference to appendRow...  exactly the kind of thing I'm trying to learn about for the case where I have to use Sheets like a database

Comment: normally yes, but that depends on the use-case. On the lame `countClicks` example above it is done that way, `r.getValue()` happens after the lock is acquired.